# How to find a Regular Expression for DFA

Tags: state-machine

Can anyone tell me how to find a regular expression for an DFA. I read and watch many materials, but I still feel confused about this.
[here is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQO3.png)

For example, with this picture above I do not see any rule because there can be arbitrary number of 0s or 1s. The only thing I know is that all strings must end with 1s.

Comment: regular expressions aren't very good at handling recursion. They can handle it sometimes, but the syntax is complicated (even for a regex). what language are you using? what flavor of regex?

Comment: @DonkeyMaster Recursion isn't needed. Regular expressions map well to to finite automata.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster I am sorry but I do not program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any loop from the end state that is valid can be done Zero or more times. Start the regex with the options for getting to the target state. There are then a pair of options for loops that get back to the target state so that is an or expression that is used zero or more times.

I could give the answer but it looks much like homework.